# How can i check if a user is Logged In or not

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire

I'm working on an angular 13 project and I am using @angular/fire 7

I created a service where i created some functions to inject. This is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Auth,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithPopup,
  signOut,
  FacebookAuthProvider,
} from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { LoginData } from '../../shared/interfaces';

import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean> | undefined;
  isLoggetOut$: Observable<boolean> | undefined;

  constructor(private afAuth: Auth) {
  }
  login( email: string, password : string ) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.afAuth, email, password)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  
}
```

I saw on the internet a varible called authState but I don't know how to use it. Is important that I can use it on angular/fire 7

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you want to achieve?
Looks like you already have a way to save the user state. You can turn the `isLoggedIn$` to a BehaviorSubject: `isLoggedIn$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);` and then in the `then` block of the `signInWithEmailAndPassword ` function, you can update the user state using `isLoggedIn$.next(true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Auth from @angular/fire/auth to get the current user

Import { Auth } from '@angulat/fire/auth';

....
uid: string;
constructor (
private auth: Auth
) {.
this.uid = this.auth.currentUser.uid;

console.log('Logged in user: ${this.uid};
}

Still waiting for docs on querying Firestore collections and documents

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged

```
 export class AuthService {
  constructor(public fireAuth: AngularFireAuth){
    this.authStatusListener();
  }

authStatusListener(){
  this.fireAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
    if(user){
      console.log(user);
      console.log('User is logged in');
    }
    else{
      console.log('User is logged out');
    }
  })
}
```

For route guards there are build-in guards:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/router-guards.md